# Neural Network in Python - Having trouble with weight matrix shapes and back prop

Tags: python, matrix, machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation

I've been struggling writing a neural network in straight python. I'm trying to get it to recognize MNIST images.

I think I must be doing something wrong when I initialize my weights.

My assumption was that because the MNIST data is data of shape 28x28, the weights should be of shape (28, something) for the first set, and the last set of weights should have a shape of (X, 1), X being the number of classes in the dataset.

One thing I'm confused about is that my ending matrix (variable l5 below) has shape (28, 1). **What do I need to do to make the output have a shape of (9, 1)?** I've printed the shapes and have realized a gap in my understanding of NNs and linear algebra:

```
l5 shape: (28, 1)
l4 shape: (28, 9)
l3 shape: (28, 14)
l2 shape: (28, 21)
l1 shape: (28, 28)
```

I think I could theoretically do a SVM (support vector machine) and multiple the (flattened) image of shape (784, 1) with a matrix of (784, 9), but I'm not sure if that's the only way to do this and if in reality, I'm far off the mark with what I've got.

Code below, based off of this tutorial: http://iamtrask.github.io/2015/07/12/basic-python-network/:

```
    syn0 = np.random.random((28, 28))
    syn1 = np.random.random((28, 21))
    syn2 = np.random.random((21, 14)) 
    syn3 = np.random.random((14, 9)) 
    syn4 = np.random.random((9, 1))
    images, labels = mndata.load_training()
    print(len(images))
    for index, image in enumerate(images):
        X = np.array(image).reshape((28, 28))
        print(X)        
        y = np.zeros((9)) # getImageCategory(fileName)
        y[labels[index]] = 1

        print(y)

        l0 = X
        l1 = sigmoid(np.dot(l0, syn0)) # + bias?
        l2 = sigmoid(np.dot(l1, syn1)) # + bias?
        l3 = sigmoid(np.dot(l2, syn2)) # + bias?
        l4 = sigmoid(np.dot(l3, syn3)) # + bias?
        l5 = sigmoid(np.dot(l4, syn4)) # + bias?

        print("l5 shape: " + str(l5.shape))
        print("l4 shape: " + str(l4.shape))
        print("l3 shape: " + str(l3.shape))
        print("l2 shape: " + str(l2.shape))
        print("l1 shape: " + str(l1.shape))
        print("Y shape: " + str(y.shape))

        l5_error = y - l5

        if index % 10 == 0:
            print("Error: " + str(np.mean(np.abs(l5_error)))) # +" | Prediction: " + str(l5))

        l5_delta = l5_error * sigmoid(l5, True) # True = derivative of sigmoid

        l4_error = l5_delta.dot(syn4.T)
        l4_delta = l4_error * sigmoid(l4, True) # True = derivative of sigmoid

        l3_error = l4_delta.dot(syn3.T)
        l3_delta = l3_error * sigmoid(l3, True) # True = derivative of sigmoid

        l2_error = l3_delta.dot(syn2.T)
        l2_delta = l2_error * sigmoid(l2, True) # True = derivative of sigmoid

        l1_error = l2_delta.dot(syn1.T)
        l1_delta = l1_error * sigmoid(l1, True) # True = derivative of sigmoid

#             print("layer_4_delta shape: " + str(l4_delta.shape))
#             print("layer_3_delta shape: " + str(l3_delta.shape))
#             print("layer_2_delta shape: " + str(l2_delta.shape))
#             print("layer_1_delta shape: " + str(l1_delta.shape))

#             print("L1 Error" + str(layer_1_delta) + " | L2 Error: " + str(layer_2_delta) + " | L3 Error: " + str(layer_3_delta) + " | L4 Error: " + str(layer_4_delta))
        # update weights
        syn4 += l4.T.dot(l5_delta)
        syn3 += l3.T.dot(l4_delta)
        syn2 += l2.T.dot(l3_delta)
        syn1 += l1.T.dot(l2_delta)
        syn0 += l0.T.dot(l1_delta)
```

Also, I understand that back-propagation is finding the gradient of the output and updating the weights to minimize the error according to the fitness function (which I may be missing now that I think about it?). **I don't understand why I had to transpose the layer when updating my weights and calculating the layer errors.**

The current error I'm getting is below, but I'm sure there are other things wrong with my code

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Username\Development\Python\updatedKernel.py", line 128, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Username\Development\Python\updatedKernel.py", line 104, in main
    l4_error = l5_delta.dot(syn4.T)
ValueError: shapes (28,9) and (1,9) not aligned: 9 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually

the shape of your input (MNIST data) is (nb_samples_in_bacth, input_dimensions) where input_dimensions = 784 = 28*28

the shape of your first set of weights is (input_dimensions, hidden_dimension), where input_dimensions = 784 = 28*28, hidden_dimension is set by user (generally should be in the same order of magnitude as your input_dimension).

the shape of your second weights is (hidden_dimension, nb_classes), where nb_class = 10 (for your 10 digits in MNIST).

Your final output should have a shape of (nb_samples_in_batch, nb_classes)

Comment: Thanks, I think this will help. So, including batch sizes in the shape of the array is necessary? Could I still do (nb_samples_in_batch, image_height, image_width), as opposed to "flattening" the image to 784? I ask because I plan on doing convolutions at some point, and I figure you cannot do them if the data is flattened.

Comment: If you are doing convolutions that you should not flatten it. You are right.